# Processing/Python development using kinect 1520 and libfreenect2 on OS X

Tags: macos, kinect, openkinect

I recently got my hands on a Xbox one kinect (1520) and I am wondering if there is a way to use the libfreenect2 library (https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) in OS X for development in python or processing (such as interactive visualisation for example?)

It doesn't have to be this specific library but it was the only one that I could find that works with the 1520 model on OSX. Other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently know of two python bindings for libfreenect2 (but I didn't try either of them):

- [pyfreenect2](https://github.com/remexre/pyfreenect2) for python 2 (or [py3freenect2](https://github.com/LovelyHorse/py3freenect2) for python 3)
- [pylibfreenect2](https://github.com/r9y9/pylibfreenect2) ("python 2.7 or later")

The second one seems to be more complete, better documented and more in line with the original libfreenect2.

The current state of those bindings is discussed in [libfreenect2 issue #280](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/280).

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out. I also found a processing library named org.openkinect.processing if some is interested.

I was disappointed to find out that none of these supports gesture recognition though.

Comment: libfreenect2 only provides the raw data, no advanced features like gesture recognition. So any library that's just a wrapper around libfreenect2 won't provided that. To get gesture recognition for free, you'd have to use the Microsoft SDK. But of course that only works on Windows 8+.

Comment: do you know if opencv can be used together with libfreenect2 to get gesture recognition?